# Probability - mixing marbles for highest probability

Tags: probability, contest-math

> A prisoner was given a chance to win his freedom. He was given two containers and 10 black marbles and 10 white marbles. He was given permission to mix the marbles any way he wished. After he was blindfolded, he was to choose a container and select a marble. If he drew a white marble he would go free; otherwise, he would remain in prison. The prisoner mixes the marbles to maximize his chance of freedom.
>   The probability (to the nearest 5 percent) that the prisoner will go free is:

I feel like if I know how the prisoner can mix the marbles to maximise his chance of picking a white marble then it'd be an easy problem, but I've no idea how to find that, especially since it sounds like a container doesn't necessarily have to have 10 marbles.

Answer (score 1):

Use redundancy. Put 19 marbles in one and one white marble in the other. This maximises the probablity. which is 9/19 *1/2 + 1/2*1 = 28/38

Making any switch from this configuration reduces the probablity.